# Add an image (alert) to DOJO dialog

Tags: dojo

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" id="errorDialog" title="An error occured" style="display: none">
<p id="errorMessage">An unexpected error occurred</p>
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" onClick="hideErrorDialog();">
OK
</button>
```

Can I add an image to a dojo dialog? to to make it appear like an alert box or something? Above is my current code?

Something like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a CSS style called 'alertIcon', something like:

```
.alertIcon {
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: url("path/to/alert/icon/alertIcon.png");
}
```

and here is some modified HTML:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" id="errorDialog" title="An error occured" style="display: none">
<div>
 <span class="dijitInline alertIcon"></span>
 <span id="errorMessage" class="dijitInline">An unexpected error occurred</span>
</div>
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" onClick="hideErrorDialog();">
OK
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. dijit.Dialog can have any content, also other dijit Widgets. Some dijit.Dialog Examples for the current 1.6.1 version:

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.1/dojo-release-1.6.1/dijit/tests/test_Dialog.html